# primeng flex grid, set col size smaller than 1/12 Angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

In primeng grid, if you have 2 columns and you want that:

1. the first one take 1/13 of the total space
2. the second one take the rest.

I have tried

```
<div class="p-grid p-nogutter">
  <div class="p-col-1">
    toto
  </div>
  <h1 class="p-col-11">titi</h1>
</div>
```

But if I want the toto div to be smaller, I found no solution.

the final goal is to achieve this whith p-grid : [image]

what i tried :

i tried  :

```
 <div class="p-d-inline-flex p-ai-center">
        <button appBackButton pButton pRipple type="button" icon="pi pi-arrow-left" class="p-button-rounded p-col-1 p-mr-4"></button>
        <div class="p-flex">
            <h1>titi</h1>
            <span>blablablabla</span>
        </div>
 </div>
```

and this is the result[image]

you notice that the button is not aligned with titi but instead with the whole second column and its not the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The grid flex only works with sections of 12. If you have an exact height/width needed for the div, you can set the flex column to be fixed.

```
<div class="p-grid p-nogutter">
  <div class="p-col-fixed" style="width:100px">
    toto
  </div>
  <h1 class="p-col">titi</h1>
</div>
```

see the fixed width column section [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/primeflex/grid)

Comment: if i use this solution and i have a second row with a div wich i want be aligned with the titi div, then the "p-offset-1" will not work anymore, thats annoying

Comment: true. a workaround for that would be to have any empty div the same length as the toto, but I agree that if you have many rows it will get annoying

Comment: Can your code work with extracting the toto from the grid?

Comment: i have added the try and the result to the origianal question